# browser mobile, is there any technology in live streaming to prevent recording?

Tags: javascript, browser, html5-video

In Android, I learned that I can disable screen recording by setting FLAG_SECURE, but I don't seem to find a similar setting on the browser. I'd like to ask if there is an api for this.

I've searched the web for a long time and I can't find a solution that prevents the recording of the screen in the browser